# libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ when installing Babel using npm on Catalina

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, macos-catalina

my error output looks like this:

```
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/simonhurst/PycharmProjects/supervalet/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v6.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

When running

`npm i -D @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`

Now I can see the issue is here :

`library not found for -lstdc++`

However have zero idea how to resolve it.

Been searching the web and stackoverflow - messing around with uninstalling Xcode reinstalling exode looking hombrew... etc but as of yet absolutely no joy.

I'm Python dev by trade so node is most certainly not my expertise. If someone could shed some light on how to resolve this issue that would be wonderful. I can't believe I'm the only one having it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow after reading many posts and many issues on GitHub... the solution in my case wasn't making sure I had Xcode installed, and the corresponding command line tools installed and making sure I'd accepted the Apple Licence agreement. It was simply a question of updating the version of node that I was using. In my case I was using version 6.x this was the version that came pre-installed on my brand new mac. Annoying. Visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to upgrade your node version. At the time of writing this the versions I upgraded to was 12.16.1 - in the event that's helpful to a future reader of this question 'n answer session :)

Really feel the error message could have been way more helpful here, but hey that's how things are some times.

Comment: Just for anyone stumble upon this. I had to upgrade node and npm.